# Android how to do setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false) from another class?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I have two class, one show images and the next only load images in background, but the problem is that the *second class* need to do `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false)` from the *first class*, and I dont know ho to do it.

**My first class:**

```
public class Galeria extends Activity {

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_galeria);

    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true); 
    ...
}
```

**My Second class:**

```
public class CargarImagenes extends AsyncTask<Object, Bitmap, Object> {

protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

other operations...
}

protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    Galeria galeria = new Galeria();


    // This is the problem!!
    galeria.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from Galeria

```
new CargarImagenes().execute(this);
```

at CargarImagenes

```
public class CargarImagenes extends AsyncTask<Object, Bitmap, Object> {

    Context context;

    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        context = (Context) params[0];
    other operations...
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        Galeria galeria = new Galeria();


        ((Activity)context).setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false)
    }

}
```

Comment: This work, Thanks a lot!. Sorry for not voting, I have enough reputation.

Comment: Also now you no need Galeria galeria = new Galeria() in onPostExecute

Answer (score 0):

When you put Galeria galeria = new Galeria(); in your seccond class, you are making a new instance of Galeria. You need to get the Galeria you created in the first class.

Try doing it like this: (change public to private) and insert the code in your first class.

```
private class CargarImagenes extends AsyncTask<Object, Bitmap, Object> {

protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

other operations...
}

protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    //Galeria galeria = new Galeria();


// This is the problem!!
pb.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

}

Where pb is your ProgressBar.

Put it in the first class like
       public ProgressBar pb;

and do something like
    pb= new ProgressBar(this); ....

Answer (score 0):

You can user bus classes or libraries, like [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) form Square, or [Bus](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) from Guava.
They can communicate each other every registered classes. Read more about it on their web pages.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you can use WeakReference to refer an object from an AsyncTask, because that is a robust way to prevent you accessing a null object.

```
public class CargarImagenes extends AsyncTask<Void, Bitmap, Object> {

    WeakReference<Activity> mActivity;

    public CargarImagenes(Activity activity){

         mActivity = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
    }

    protected Object doInBackground(Void... params) {

        other operations...
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

        Activity activity = mActivity.get();
        if(activity != null){    
            activity.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        }
    }    
}
```

then you can create the CargarImagenes like this

```
CargarImagenes task = new CargarImagenes(this);
```

and execute it.